# Powershell script to read filesystem and csv files and return JSON object?

Tags: php, json, powershell, csv

The code below reads the filesystem and returns a JSON object to a php page which is then parsed out.

I'm trying to add a "Questions" attribute which reads a csv file

"$*.FullName + "\" + $*.Name + "-questions.csv"

and returns a JSON object which will be nested within the parent.  Right now it's returning just a "[". not sure why? any help

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$path
)
function Add-Tabstops{
    param($Count)
    $tabs = ""
    for($i=0; $i -lt $Count; $i++){$tabs += "  "}
    return $tabs
}
function Read-Questions($name){
    $name = $name + "-questions.csv"
    if(Test-Path($name)){
        $questions= Import-CSV $name | ConvertTo-JSON
        return "["
                $questions
                "]"
    }
    else{
        return "None"
    }
}
function Process-Path{
     param($Path)
     if (Test-Path "$path"){
        $source = $path.Split("\")
        $source = $source[($source.Length -1)]
        Output-JsonChildren -Path "$path" -Source $source
     }
     else {
        return '"No Objects Found!"'
     }
}

function Output-JsonChildren{
    param($Path, $Level = 1, $Source)
    return $(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory | Where-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{
        (Add-Tabstops $Level) +
        "{`n" + 
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) +
        "`"Name`"`: `"$($_.Name)`"," + 
        "`n" +
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) +
        "`"Image`"`: `"$($_.Name)`"," + 
        "`n" +
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) +
        "`"displayName`"`: `"$((Get-Content($($_.FullName + "\" + $_.Name + ".txt"))).split('-')[0])`"," + 
        "`n" +
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) +
        "`"Attribute1`"`: `"$((Get-Content($($_.FullName + "\" + $_.Name + ".txt"))).split('-')[1])`"," + 
        "`n" +
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) +
        "`"Attribute2`"`: `"$((Get-Content($($_.FullName + "\" + $_.Name + ".txt"))).split('-')[2])`"," + 
        "`n" +
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) +
        "`"Attribute3`"`: `"$((Get-Content($($_.FullName + "\" + $_.Name + ".txt"))).split('-')[3])`"," + 
        "`n" +
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) +
        "`"Attribute4`"`: `"$Source`"," + 
        "`n" +
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) +
        "`"Questions`"`: `"$(Read-Questions($($_.FullName + "\" + $_.Name)))`"," + 
        "`n" +
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1)) + 
        "`"children`": ["+ 
        $(if($_.psiscontainer){"`n" + (Output-JsonChildren -Path $_.FullName -Level ($Level+2))+ "`n" + (Add-Tabstops ($Level+1))}) +
        "]`n" + 
        (Add-Tabstops ($Level)) +
        "}"
    }) -join ",`n"
}

$JSON = Process-Path -Path $path

"["
$JSON
"]"
```

Comment: for the filepaths? it can find the files fine

Comment: I had issues when putting newlines in my cells. Maybe experiment with taking them out? `ConvertTo-JSON -Compress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
return "["
        $questions
        "]"
```

Let's reformat these three lines and some semi-colons as explicit line endings, but leave the functionality identical:

```
return "[";
$questions;
"]";
```

Does that make it clear why the function always returns `[`?

You want:

```
return '[' + $Questions.ToString() + ']';
```